# How do I rotate an SVG path element without it moving in circles?

Tags: css, svg, svg-animate

I have an SVG with 3 paths but only needed em to rotate continually. This worked well on an SVG with one path but not with this one and I got a few others that I could like to rotate on a fixed position.
[Here is the source code with preview!](https://codepen.io/JonthueM/pen/BaQLJmo)

```
  .rotate {
  animation: rotation 8s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can transform the rotation origin, the default origin is the upper left corner.
to rotate a item around its center you have to transform the origin.

```
.rotate {
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    animation: rotation 8s infinite linear;
}
```

Comment: But now it moves slightly from the center https://codepen.io/JonthueM/pen/BaQLJmo